# Is there a PowerShell logging module that uses StreamWriter to write to a text file?

Tags: powershell, logging, module, streamwriter

I checked a dozen logging modules published at PowerShellGallery.com but every one of them uses a variation of the `Write-Output` or piping to `Out-File` approach which is really inefficient for bigger log files (every log command involves opening the file, reading to the end, and then writing an entry).

Before I write my own logging module, I am wondering if there is a more efficient version of a logging library that uses a `StreamWriter.WriteLine` approach. I only need to write to a console and/or a text file and I do not want to have any dependencies on the .NET code. Any ideas?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, and decided to rolled my own.  `StreamWriter` is measurably faster than `out-file` for sure. Script-logging is one of those things that is so specific to each environment that there really can't be a one-size-fits-all solution. This is why the Gods gave us Splunk.

Comment: [This comparison](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gbordier/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file/) indicates that StreamWriter is indeed efficient and the implementation is simple. A tool like [Log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) will give you some [additional features](https://www.vioreliftode.com/index.php/powershell-logging-using-apache-log4net/) if you're looking for a library.

Comment: Looks like nothing is available, so I rolled out my own implementation. Will post an answer, when its ready in GitHub and PowerShellGallery.com.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since there seems to be no publicly available module that would do this, I wrote my own: [StreamLogging](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/StreamLogging). It can write to console and/or text file (it can also copy error messages to a separate error file). Documentation is at [GitHub](https://github.com/alekdavis/StreamLogging).